# DOI in IEEEtran bibliography

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, doi

The [IEEE Citation Reference](http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf) specifies that a DOI should be provided for electronic articles without page numbers. However, `IEEEtran.bst` appears to provide no such functionality. What is the best way to get DOI numbers in the bibliography?

Bonus if the solution also

- optionally makes display of DOI conditional on a lack of page numbers for conference proceedings only; and/or
- hyperlinks the DOI (e.g. through the `doi` or `uri` packages).

I'll accept a solution that involves editing `IEEEtran.bst`—this is the approach I'm working on now—but would prefer one that doesn't, if possible.

Comment: Have you asked Michael Shell (author of `IEEEtran`) about this?

Comment: @JosephWright I sent him an email concurrently with this question, and I'll report what I hear back.

Comment: And so you heard nothing back?

Comment: He reported in August 2012 that DOI functionality is on the to-do list, and that there is more than just DOI to consider (e.g. ArXiv), so it is more involved than just a quick patch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've created a [patch](https://gist.github.com/3373556) to `IEEEtranN.bst` that does the trick, including the "bonus" features.

Comment: I think the better way would be to create a new `bst` file like `IEEEtranNDoi.bst` and provide a MWE which shows how to use it ...

Comment: Applying the patch generates the new `bst` file. I could provide that, although for the moment I am more interested in comments on the changes. The usage should be (and in this case, is) transparent to the user as compared to the current version of `IEEEtranN.bst`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Note the Q&A to enhance the DOI with a hyperlink: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394811/hyperlink-in-doi-in-ieeetran-bibliography

Comment: See also https://people.kth.se/~maguire/myIEEEtran.bst

Answer (score 9):

I use this approach to hyperlink the article title:

First, copy `IEEEtran.bst` to `IEEEtranDOI.bst`.

In the `ENTRY` field around line 250, add a line like this:

```
  dayfiled
+ doi
  edition
```

In the `FUNCTION {format.article.title}` field around line 1400, add a line like this:

```
  "title" bibinfo.check
+ doi empty$ {} { "\href{https://doi.org/" doi * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * } if$
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
```

Then use `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranDOI}` and it should work. Use `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` if you like hyperlinks invisible.

This is a patch I created for today's IEEEtran.bst using `diff -c IEEEtran.bst IEEEtranDOI.bst`:

```
*** IEEEtran.bst        2015-08-26 16:56:09.000000000 -0400
--- IEEEtranDOI.bst     2016-01-20 14:17:48.216975400 -0500
***************
*** 262,267 ****
--- 262,268 ----
      chapter
      day
      dayfiled
+     doi
      edition
      editor
      howpublished
***************
*** 1419,1424 ****
--- 1420,1426 ----
      }
    if$
    "title" bibinfo.check
+   doi empty$ {} { "\href{https://doi.org/" doi * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * } if$
    duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
      { quote.close 'this.status.quote :=
        is.last.char.not.punct
```

And here's an MWE to test your IEEEtranDOI.bst:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Example,
        author = {Author, The},
        doi = {10.1000/182},
        journal = {Awesome Journal},
        title = {{This is the title, click to go to doi}},
        year = {2016},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranDOI}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I never assume anything about academicians.

Comment: I didn't say you told to do so. It's a generic comment.

Comment: Some comments are completely unnecessary and/or out of place. (This is a generic comment.)

Comment: and you are the winner of this argument. Have a badge.

Comment: Do you have a link to this generated "IEEEtranDOI" file? How this relate to the @ezod patch?

Comment: @ErnestoIglesias no, I do not offer a download. My answer has all the information necessary to generate the file. I have not compared this one to the other answer in detail, but mine looks much shorter - probably because I only add the hyperlink without changing the visual appearance of the document in any way.