# DOI in reference

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, ieee-style, doi

I am writing a letter to IEEE EDL. They asked me to add DOI in the references. I am using IEEEtran style. The .bib file contains the DOI for each reference. But it is not displayed in the output. How to show the DOI in output?

Document class IEEEtran.cls

Sample BibTex entry

```
@ARTICLE{r6, 
author={A. C. Seabaugh and Q. Zhang}, 
journal={Proceedings of the IEEE}, 
title={Low-Voltage Tunnel Transistors for Beyond CMOS Logic}, 
year={2010}, 
volume={98}, 
number={12}, 
pages={2095-2110}, 
keywords={CMOS logic circuits;MOSFET;}, 
doi={10.1109/JPROC.2010.2070470}, 
ISSN={0018-9219}, 
month={Dec},}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you are using `biblatex`, you could pass `doi=true` as option, but please add some details.

Comment: @TeXnician - Have the IEEE journals started accepting biblatex-based bibliographies? If not, it may be better to stick with bibtex-based suggestions.

Comment: Please edit your posting and provide information about the precise document class and bibliography style you employ. (There are several IEEEtran-sponsored bibliography styles out there...) Please also provide an example of a bib entry that contains a `doi` field.

Comment: I am using bibtex

Comment: Relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67444/8666

Comment: What about this post:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to (a) change the label of the `doi` field to `note` and (b) encase the doi string in a `\url{...}` directive. (The `IEEEtran` document class loads the `url` package automatically.)

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@ARTICLE{r6,
author  = {A. C. Seabaugh and Q. Zhang},
journal = {Proceedings of the IEEE},
title   = {Low-Voltage Tunnel Transistors for Beyond {CMOS} Logic},
year    = {2010},
volume  = {98},
number  = {12},
pages   = {2095-2110},
keywords= {CMOS logic circuits;MOSFET;},
note    = {doi: \url{10.1109/JPROC.2010.2070470}},
ISSN    = {0018-9219},
month   = dec,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, you should change the month field from `month={Dec}` to `month=dec` (no curly braces, lowercase "d"). You should also encase the word "CMOS" in curly braces to prevent BibTeX from lowercasing it.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I also found this [link](https://gist.github.com/philmtd/f75f4071779ae053d86e04db525466f7) which edited IEEEtran.bst. Will the accecpt it if i edited .bst file?

Comment: @Nithin - I took a look at the bst file in the link you provided. It defines a function called `format.doi`, but it's used only to format entries of type `@inproceedings` and `@proceedings`. So, I don't think it would be of much use for you, at least not for entries of type (say) `@article`.